# Python and Selenium, Trying to accept cookies on website results: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, html, selenium

I'm trying to enter a website with python (selenium) code and I'm required to accept cookies. For some reason, no matter what I've tried, I always get the result: Unable to locate element. Below 'accept cookies button' from the website's HTML code.

```
<button tabindex="0" title="Hyväksy kaikki evästeet" aria-label="Hyväksy kaikki evästeet" class="message-component message-button no-children buttons-row" path="[0,3,1]">Hyväksy kaikki evästeet</button>
```

I've tried the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep
import pandas as pd 
import requests as req

class trackerBot(): 
        
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        # Tried with and without implicitly wait
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
            
    def loadWebsite(self, uri):
            
        self.driver.get(uri)
        cookies_accept_btn = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[3]/div[5]/button[2]')
        cookies_accept_btn.click()
                
def main():
    bot = trackerBot()
    bot.loadWebsite("https://www.tori.fi")        
    return(0)
    
main()
```

Can someone advise what I'm missing?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: is it in an iframe/

Comment: YES!! Now I got it working after switching to iframe where that element located. Many thanks, you are a saviour! :D

Comment: ok good. I added an answer you can select if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element may be in an iframe.
Use switch_to:
[Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python)

```
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in find_element_by_xpath ("//button[@title='Hyväksy kaikki evästeet']")

if this can not overcome your issue than take reference from this site:

https://devhints.io/xpath

Comment: That didn't work but thanks for the link to the website! Will try to find the answer from there.

Answer (score 0):

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//button[@title='Hyväksy kaikki evästeet']"))).click()
```

Use a Webdriver wait for the element and find the element by xpath with it's data-attribute title.

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Isn't this line self.driver.implicitly_wait(10) doing the same trick? Or what is the difference?

Comment: Slightly difference is the wait is for the element to be clickable not wait 10 seconds.

Comment: Alright, thanks! But this didn't work either :(

Comment: I can't find that element myself. Is that the right element?

Comment: It was located in the iframe and now I got it working! Thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 0):

The 'accept cookies window' was in the iframe so I had to switch to that frame to be able to locate the element. Switching done with following code:

```
iframe = self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//iframe[@id="sp_message_iframe_433571"]')

self.driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66581229/3) to the question [SOLVED Python and Selenium, Trying to accept cookies on website results: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66581229/solved-python-and-selenium-trying-to-accept-cookies-on-website-results-unable) by the OP [Böhmeli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12297468/b%c3%b6hmeli) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>